# android horizontal swipe list item

Tags: android, list, swipe

must implement this design and functionality, but can not make elements horizontal swipe in  list like picture on link. 
I will be glad for any suggestions)

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this library https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview you can implement this.

Comment: all "swipe" attribs are red in the custom view  when use view com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView in my layout, for example: swipe:swipeActionLeft="[reveal | dismiss]"
     swipe:swipeActionRight="[reveal | dismiss]"
   swipe:swipeMode="[none | both | right | left]"  ...maybe know any solutions ?

Comment: downvoted because the link is dead now.